# Data table sort by date only sorts the day

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, datatables, date-sorting

I have a `Datatable` which is a project list and i want to sort the date column into descending.
It works but it sorts only the day.

What I want is the last added project to come first.

My script is:

```
<script>
       $(function(){
                  /* Initialize Bootstrap Datatables Integration */
            App.datatables();

            /* Initialize Datatables */
            $('#manage-table').dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] } ],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, -1], [10, 20, "All"]],
                "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]] //date column

            });

            /* Add placeholder attribute to the search input */
            $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search'); 
       });
       </script>
```

Comment: Can you add enough HTML to your question to reproduce the issue?

Comment: what date format is being used? A demo that replicates this would help

Comment: 23-02-2015 this format

Comment: This might be helpful resource. https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-uk

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend DataTables sorting functionality to sort dates in format `DD-MM-YYYY`. Judging from your initialization code, most likely you're using DataTables 1.9.x.

See updated code below, I omitted the code that hasn't been changed:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-uk2-pre": function (a) {
        if (a == null || a == "") {
            return 0;
        }
        var ukDatea = a.split('-');
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },
    "date-uk2-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "date-uk2-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});

/* Initialize Datatables */
$('#manage-table').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
       { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
       { "sType": "date-uk2", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, -1], [10, 20, "All"]],
    "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]] //date column
});
```

I have modified original `date_uk` sorting plug-in to sort by `DD-MM-YYYY` instead of `DD/MM/YYYY`.

See [DataTables 1.9.x `date_uk` sorting plug-in](http://legacy.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#date_uk) or [DataTables 1.10.x `date_uk` sorting plug-in](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-uk) for more information.